# Adding a Div tag to wrap around LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to dynamically add a pair of Div tags and a class to wrap a set of elements in the DOM. How would I go about doing this?

**Html**

```
<div class="right-bottom"> <!-- this is the div tag I would like to add to wrap the content below-->
    <li class="">
        <a href="">Diffusion Tensor Imaging</a>
        <article class="article-body" data-asynchtml-target="">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </article>
     </li>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement('div');
</script>
```

Comment: Well, this is not much so far :). Have you tried the jQuery documentation?

Comment: [`<li>` can only be a child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li), so wrapping them in a `<div>` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this. Instead, wrap the contents of the li in a div, not the li itself.

Comment: I didn't mean to downvote this, I misclicked and by the time I noticed it was locked.

Comment: @ach would you mind giving an up vote then please? Thank you!

Comment: @Amechi It won't let me do that either... if you edit your question it will allow me to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: get parent, detach element, append wrap to parent, append element to wrap.

```
function wrapElement(element) {
    var parent = element.parentNode,
        wrap   = document.createElement('div');

    wrap.classList.add('wrap');
    element.remove();
    parent.appendChild(wrap);
    wrap.appendChild(element);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hagovune/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: OK, but if he's using jQuery, why do this in long vanilla?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.wrap()` with appropriate selector to target li elements. something like this:

```
$('.article-body').closest('li').wrap('<div class="right-bottom"></div>')
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: OP doesn't specifically ask for jQuery

Comment: @GabrielIzaias Well they did tag it so this answer fully satisfies

Comment: @kapa That's OP's mistake, not MilindAnatwar's -- although it would be worth mentioning in this answer.

Comment: @kapa I know this is not a preferred method by -1 for just testing around with javascript and trying things out is quite rude.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I think an answer that does not warn the OP that what he wants is not a good idea, is *not useful* (exactly what the tooltip on my downvote arrow says).

Comment: @kapa I disagree, a comment would be better place to question the use of an `li` in a `div`. But this answer exactly matches the question.

Comment: @kapa Your quality concern should be with the OP not the answer. To quote the title of the question "Adding a Div tag to wrap around LI elements" so anyone coming to this post should be trying to achieve the same thing. Even if its against spec it still answers the question that was asked.

Comment: @AshleyMedway That is a quite ignorant attitude. I had quality concerns with the question as well (no research effort), btw. So you say just quickly answer, collect the rep, and move on to the next one? That's quite common now on SO, so no problem, just asking :). I think everyone else coming to this post should get a big notification in their face "This is not a good idea, this is how you do it correctly", instead of ignorant few-lines-of-code answers.

Comment: @kapa It's not to do with rep, and I agree that questions without research are the bane of SO. But that is exactly what the comments / voting system is for. All I am saying is that I disagree with the placement of your comment.